# Get and set selected option using template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates

How could I change selected option for dropdown list using javascript or jQuery?

```html
<select id ="someId" name="someName">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select><br>

<label>item1:</label>
<input type="text" name="item1" value= <%= someValue %>><br>
<label>Line item2:</label>
<input type="color" name="item2" value= <%= someValue1 %>><br>
<label>item3:</label>
<input type="number" name="item3" min=0 value= <%= someValue2 %>><br>
<label>item4:</label>
<input type="color" name="item4" value= <%= someValue3 %>><br>
```

I had this html saved in a variable called `template`. How could I get and set the selected option in dropdown list, so the result will be the same template with one of three options selected. Thank you in advance. Example of result:

```html
<select id ="someId" name="someName">
    <option selected>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select><br>

<label>item1:</label>
<input type="text" name="item1" value= <%= someValue %>><br>
<label>Line item2:</label>
<input type="color" name="item2" value= <%= someValue1 %>><br>
<label>item3:</label>
<input type="number" name="item3" min=0 value= <%= someValue2 %>><br>
<label>item4:</label>
<input type="color" name="item4" value= <%= someValue3 %>><br>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the result will be the same template with one of three options selected." Are you trying to examine the ```<select>``` and its ```<options>``` markup, and then build a separate chunk of markup that lists these as ```<inputs>``` with ```<labels>``` instead?

Comment: Also when you say "I had this html saved in a variable", what do you mean, precisely? A JavaScript variable? Can you provide that code?

Comment: I am using text.js and Backbone.define([
    "backbone.marionette",
    "text!/js/path/template.html"
], function(
    Marionette,
    template
) {// here I can use variable template});

Comment: It sounds like, architecturally speaking, you have a lot more happening in your code than you're providing. The Backbone/Marionette way to do this would be to create a Backbone.Collection that stores your options (with each option being a Backbone.Model). The option Models have a ```selected``` attribute. Then you could create a Marionette.CollectionView to render the Collection. Your CollectionView would have a template (e.g. Underscore or Handlebars) that injects the Models' data and renders the two sets of markup.

Comment: The thing is that options in dropdown are constants, I don't need separated views for them. They are always the same (One, Two, Three). So why can't I get select element with options and get/set needed value?

Comment: Totally puzzled by what you're trying to do, then. Even if they're constants, creating a Collection, even with data that's just Bootstrapped as a JSON object, will provide you with the means to sync two different layouts of the same data. Since you're already using Marionette, this makes a lot more sense than trying to traverse the ```<select>``` and dynamically create a different set of markup.

Comment: I'm trying to set selected for an option that's in template. I even get the result, that I want to receive. Could you give me an example of code, so I can totally understand, what you are suggesting.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar JavaScript way to do this:

```
// code for setting item_id
var template = '<select id ="someId" name="someName"> \
    <option ';
if(item_id == 1) {
    template += 'selected';
}
template += ' >One</option> <option ';
if(item_id == 2) {
    template += 'selected';
}
template += ' >Two</option> <option ';
if(item_id == 3) {
    template += 'selected';
}
template += ' >Three</option> \
</select><br> \
<label>item1:</label> \
<input type="text" name="item1" value= <%= someValue %>><br> \
<label>Line item2:</label> \
<input type="color" name="item2" value= <%= someValue1 %>><br> \
<label>item3:</label> \
<input type="number" name="item3" min=0 value= <%= someValue2 %>><br> \
<label>item4:</label> \
<input type="color" name="item4" value= <%= someValue3 %>><br>';
// code for injecting into DOM
```

It's a bit more typing and breaking up, but it will solve your issue for setting the template.

If you're up for it, you can do this utilizing a small amount of PHP instead, which won't be visible to the average user (requires some serious hacking to view active PHP code if you don't have access to the server). Alter the template this way:

```
// code for setting item_id
var template = '<?php $selected = ' + item_id + ' ?> \
<select id ="someId" name="someName"> \
    <option <?php if($selected === 1){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >One</option> \
    <option <?php if($selected === 2){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >Two</option> \
    <option <?php if($selected === 3){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >Three</option> \
</select><br> \
<label>item1:</label> \
<input type="text" name="item1" value= <%= someValue %>><br> \
<label>Line item2:</label> \
<input type="color" name="item2" value= <%= someValue1 %>><br> \
<label>item3:</label> \
<input type="number" name="item3" min=0 value= <%= someValue2 %>><br> \
<label>item4:</label> \
<input type="color" name="item4" value= <%= someValue3 %>><br>';
// code for injecting into DOM
```

The first line of PHP sets the value of the variable `$selected` and the next 3 lines check for that value and set the correct option to selected. This is the quickest fix I know of, but it requires a PHP processing engine such as Apache. Most hosting has it enabled (at least that I've worked with).

Comment: thanks, but I need only javascript or jQuery solution

Comment: @I.N I have added a JavaScript solution as well. Without seeing the surrounding functionality, it's hard to pinpoint the best solution for this situation. I hope this helps put you in the right frame of mind.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question an easy way to set an option would be like this using just jQuery.

```
$(function(){
setOption(2);//selects third option 
});

function setOption(option){
var itter = 0;
$("select option").each(function(){
    if(itter = option)
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
});
}
```

Of course if you are using a template you can use a plugin like jQuery Template 
create an object and use it alongside your template
CDN : http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js

```
function selectedOptions(){
    this.opt1 = "";
    this.opt2 = "selected";
    this.opt3 = "";
}
var options = new selectedOptions();
$.tmpl(yourTemplateVariable, options);
```

You can attach a listener to the select element and when it changes change the options object to reflect the change.

your template would need these values

```
<option ${opt1}>One</option>
<option ${opt2}>Two</option>
<option ${opt3}>Three</option>
```

I doubt this is the answer you were looking for, but maybe it can be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started on doing things the Marionette™ way: http://codepen.io/benjarwar/pen/YyvOOx

The basic idea is, since you want some sort of synchronization between two different sets of markup with the same underlying data, Marionette is perfect for applying an MVC architecture and using the power of templates/Views to display that data in different contexts.

In my opinion, structuring your application with some sort of MVC architecture (Backbone/Marionette, Angular, React, et al) gives you much more maintainable code. Avoid falling into the trap of writing spaghetti jQuery. Learn how to create event driven JavaScript that separates concerns between a logic/controller layer and a display/view layer.

**Update:** I went ahead and fleshed this out a little more, adding event bindings so that when you change the selected option in the dropdown, the InputsView re-renders, highlighting the currently selected option.

HTML:

```
<div id="select" class="container"></div>
<div id="inputs" class="container"></div>

<script id="select-template" type="text/html">
  <select class="select-menu">
    <% _.each(items, function(option){ %>
      <option name="<%= option.name %>" <% if (option.selected) { %>selected<% } %>>
        <%= option.value %>
      </option>
    <% }); %>
  </select>
</script>

<script id="inputs-template" type="text/html">
  <% _.each(items, function(option){ %>
    <label <% if (option.selected) { %>class="selected"<% } %>><%= option.name %>:</label>
    <input type="text" name="<%= option.name %>" value="<%= option.value %>">
    <br>
  <% }); %>
</script>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin: 20px;
}

label, input {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.selected {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

JS:

```
var data = [
  { name: "Foo", value: 'bar', selected: false },
  { name: "Baz", value: 'quz', selected: true },
  { name: "Norf", value: 'zap', selected: false }
];

// create a new Collection from the initial data
var options = new Backbone.Collection(data);

// a View for rendering the dropdown
var SelectView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#select-template",

  // set your ui hash
  ui: {
    "select": ".select-menu"
  },

  // fire an event when the select menu changes
  events: {
    "change @ui.select": "handleSelectChange"
  },

  handleSelectChange: function(e) {
    var $selected = $(e.target).find(":selected"),
        selectedName = $selected.attr("name"),
        selectedModel = this.collection.findWhere({ name: selectedName });

    // on select change, first deselect any previously selected Models
    this.collection.forEach(function(model, index) {
      model.set("selected", false);
    });

    // set the newly selected Model
    selectedModel.set("selected", true);
  }
});

// a View for rendering the inputs
var InputsView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#inputs-template",

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "change", this.render);
  }
});

// instantiate the Views with the same Collection
var inputsView = new InputsView({collection: options});
var selectView = new SelectView({collection: options});


// create a region manager (alternatively build a Marionette.App, or use a LayoutView, etc.)
var rm = new Marionette.RegionManager();

// set up your regions
var regions = rm.addRegions({
  select: "#select",
  inputs: "#inputs"
});

// show your views
regions.select.show(selectView);
regions.inputs.show(inputsView);
```

JS dependencies: jQuery, Underscore, Backbone, Marionette

Answer (score 0):

The way I've solved my problem is really dirty, but it's working, so an answer is

```js
<label>Somelabel:</label>
<select name="someName" value= <%= someValue %>>
    <option value="One"<% if (someValue === "One") print("selected")%>>One</option>
    <option value="Two"<% if (someValue === "Two") print("selected")%>>Two</option>
    <option value="Three"<% if (someValue === "Three") print("selected")%>>Three</option>
</select><br>
```